# Where can I find heroku uptime history?

Tags: heroku

I need to know the heroku historical average uptime as an input to compute our overall estimate future uptime.

I've looked without success on status.heroku.com and on google.

**Where can I find data about heroku platform average uptime history ?**

Comment: For your app, or for the service itself? For Heroku's services I think this is the best you're going to get: https://status.heroku.com/incidents

Comment: For the heroku platform (question edited). Are you saying that the only way do compute this is to go through all the incident and manually compute it myself ? This would sound really surprising...

Comment: In my experience, Heroku is pretty bad at communicating about outages. But I don't work for them and [customer service-related questions are off-topic here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/354577). I suggest you contact Heroku support to ask if there's a better way.